# Keep keyboard backlight on? Lenovo Thinkpad P53S

Tags: keyboard, lenovo, thinkpad

On 20.04. Every time I wake it from sleep, the keyboard backlight is off and I have to re-enable it with Fn+space. I would like it to just always be enabled.